# Merge changes from TFS to local copy of same branch (master)

Tags: tfs

Apologies if this is a stupid question, but ...

We are a very small team (3) working all on the master branch from TFS, making local changes, then checking them in (and if necessary merging). The bit that puzzles me is how to merge changes down from the server to my local copy BEFORE checking in. I am sure it something really simple that I have missed/forgotten about this particular scenario in TFS.

Can anyone remind me?

Comment: Are you using TFVC or git? I posted a TFVC answer, but realised it might be git, let me know and I can delete it if its wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TFS you just do a "Get Latest" in Visual Studio.

If you're working on the command line you can:

```
cd \Code
tf get . /recursive
```

Or just `tf get` (depends how you're workspace is mapped).

If there is a conflict between a local change you have made and a change your colleague has checked in on the server, TFVC will attempt a merge, and if it cannot be resolved, will mark the file as a conflicting change for you to resolve.

TFVC also does a get latest of any file you attempt to check in before you are allowed to check in, forcing a merge at this point too. This can be quite confusing if someone has changed many files and yourself only one, as the get latest will only be for the one you changed, in those cases I usually get everything again.

Comment: Thanks, I guess my "Get Latests" have been working invisibly up to now due to no conflicts! And thanks for the tip on the last point!